# Resharper - Issue with App_GlobalResources

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, resharper

I've got an issue when I try to use App_GlobalResources/Common.resx in views.
I write, for example:

```
@Resources.Common.Yes
```

The solution builds without issues however reshaper shows an error.

Reshaper tries to use Common from a different project and that one is internal.

Regards

Comment: Does it work when using the complete namespace, e. g. `@This.Is.Your.Namespace.Resources.Common.Yes`?

Comment: Nope, only works for
`My_namespace.App_GlobalResources.Common.Yes`